# Adding function stops whole script?

Tags: php, mysql

I used a `mysql_query` to retrieve info from my database and print the info to a table.

```
<?php
    $ranklist = [60, 250, 550, 900, 1350, 1800, 2350, 3000];
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>"$row[uname]"</td>";
        function getrank($userrank) {
            foreach ($ranklist as &$val) {
                if ($val > $userrank) {
                    return $val;
                }
            }
        }
        echo "<td>"$row[rank]"</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

The database has the variables `id`, `uname`, and `rank`. I want to determine the rank by reading from the database and extrapolating from the array. When I take out the function `getrank`, it prints the rank in the database, but when I add it, it doesn't work whatsoever.

Comment: A function inside a loop?are you sure?

Comment: btw, you never call the function, what do you expect anyway..

Comment: The longer I look at this, the more I feel the urge to say: You can't just throw random code-looking text together and call it a PHP application. There's more wrong with this than just the function issue.

Comment: Also, "it doesn't work whatsoever" hardly provides any information about what doesn't work. Is there no output? Do you get an error? Does the program not terminate? Etc.

Comment: "whatsoever" is perfectly descriptive, as the code does not do anything. (i.e. no error, no output, etc.) @CamilStaps

Comment: It's a poor description. If you would say "doesn't output anything whatsoever", that would be fine. But "doesn't work whatsoever" leaves all three possibilities I mentioned (and more) open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put your function in a while loop. That means you're essentially trying to redeclare your function every time you iterate the loop, which isn't possible.

Instead, place the function outside, for example, at the top of the page, and merely call it from within the loop.

```
<?php
function getrank($userrank) {
    $ranklist = array(60, 250, 550, 900, 1350, 1800, 2350, 3000);
    foreach ($ranklist as &$val) {
        if ($val > $userrank) {
            return $val;
        }
    }
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['uname']}</td>";
    echo "<td>" . getrank($row['rank']) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

But in this case, you actually don't need the function at all. You're using it only once, and it isn't a very long code. So you can just put it all together, without a function, like this:

```
<?php
$ranklist = array(60, 250, 550, 900, 1350, 1800, 2350, 3000);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['uname']}</td>";
    foreach ($ranklist as &$val) {
        if ($val > $userrank) {
            echo "<td>$val</td>";
            break; // exit the foreach loop
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Also note that I fixed your variables encapsulated in the strings, and the faulty array declaration.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd active error reporting or looked at your error logs, you'd see "Fatal error, cannot redeclare function `getrank`". You're declaring the function in a loop. That means, on every iteration of the loop, it's trying to redeclare the function. That can't work.

You're also never calling the function at all, so I'm not sure why it's even there.

Not to mention the syntax errors with your messed up quotes and variables inside.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define functions inside a while statement. Try something like:

```
   function getrank($userrank) {
        $ranklist = [60, 250, 550, 900, 1350, 1800, 2350, 3000];
        foreach ($ranklist as $val) {
            if ($val > $userrank) {
                return $val;
            }
        }
    }


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['uname']."</td>";
    $rank = getrank($row['rank']);
    echo "<td>$rank</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As guys here said you can't declare function in the loop. But if you still want to do this you can use anonymous functions.

So, you need just change this:

```
function getrank($userrank) {
        foreach ($ranklist as &$val) {
            if ($val > $userrank) {
                return $val;
            }
        }
    }
```

To this:

```
function($userrank) {
        foreach ($ranklist as &$val) {
            if ($val > $userrank) {
                return $val;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And that does what exactly?

Comment: My fault... but if write like $var = function($userrank)... this should work... Forgot about return value.